# How can I project data annotations from a model to a view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations

I have a `Catalog` EF entity that I decorate in a metadata class as shown:

```
public partial class Catalog
{
    [Editable(false)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [Required()]
    [MaxLength(300)]
    [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources), Name = "CatalogName")]
    public string CatalogName { get; set; }
}
```

When I expose this to a Razor view these values show properly. However, I am wanting to use a view model as such:

```
public class CatalogViewModel
{
    private readonly Catalog _catalog;

    // I want the attributes for Catalog.CatalogName to apply here.
    public String CatalogName
    {
        get { return _catalog.CatalogName; }
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use the validation and display information from the entity as is on the view model. I don't have access to the type `Resources` however. Is there a way i could somehow project this information from model to view model?

**Edits:**

Business layer validation is annotated on the entities. And I want to keep it that way so that the validation and display information is in a single location. I also use a pattern of 1 view model for every view. So having annotation on here violates DRY in a way I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Why is your `Catalog_Meta` inside your entity? I would argue that your ViewModel should be attached to your Metadatatype for validation and not your entities.

Comment: The metadata type is just so that I can annotate an entity object generated by Entity Framework. I'll have to simplify my question.

Comment: MetaData and validation should be used in ViewModel for the properties you want to expose to view.

Comment: I'm talking about separation of concerns. Your entity layer should not contain details about UI validation or how they are displayed. Ideally you would map the entities to an object model which is appropriate for your UI, then you can apply the annotations there.

Comment: Then how would I project those validations from the object model to the view model?

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for telling me how I should architect my application. Thanks also for not answering my question. I'd be fine having an extra Object Layer to represent my business layer, but EF5 is so light, I decided not to. I am wanting to have my validation in a central location, and view models are not central at all. For instance, a `Catalog` has a property `CatalogName` that has a maximum width of 300. Asserting that on every single view model that exposes `Catalog` is a gross violation of DRY. Applying it to an entity makes the most sense, and is what MSDN suggests.

Comment: @Forty-Two, I don't really want to expose the entity as a whole to my view model. The view model represents an amalgam of multiple entities that are to be combined together.

Comment: OK, so I'm not going to get another answer. I take it that the consensus herein is that I mark every view model in my entire application that deals with `Catalog` with the same validation logic. That is what I will do. >_>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are really worried about violating DRY principles, though I'm not sure that is a valid concern because I would rather have the option to specify different validations based on the context (which view/viewmodel of how the Catalog entity was being used), you can check out this:

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/

You will build your validation rules in a class (instead of annotations), then you can create different versions based on the context, inheritance hierarchies, and you can apply the validation in your business layer or your UI layer. The project contains hooks to integrate nicely with MVC3.

Comment: In my opinion, data validation should be specified on the data model itself. There is also some validation that one might be useful on the view/view model layer, but it is the business layer that should define data integrity. In my situation, the validation was intermediate validation, several data entities were being combined to create a new single data entity. In this intermediate state, it didn't make sense for all of the entities to be present in their entirety, so i was using the view model as a stand in. ...

Comment: So in this case, the view model has to do some validation, but it needs to be obedient to the validation of the business layer as well. I've devised a solution that uses `Validator` and `IValidatableObject` where by the view model's validation process can reference and abide by the business layer's validation rules. DRY is important to me when it comes to business logic especially, because distribution of rules in multiple places too often causes differentiation when rules change.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here to my question using Manual Validation.

http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

It works, but isn't quite what I was looking for.

```
public class CatalogViewModel  : IValidatableObject
{
    private readonly Catalog _catalog;

    public String CatalogName
    {
        get { return _catalog.CatalogName; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext a_validationContext)
    {
       // Call Validator.TryValidateObject on _catalog and return results.
    }
}
```